# Js angular bug only on Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I have the following code:

```
$http.post(constants.path+'address.php', {form}).then(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log("success");
            });
        }
```

Only on Safari I get the following error:

```
'SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'. Expected a ':' following the property name 'form'.
```

Every other browser don't complain about this code. Any ideas ?

EDIT 1: The whole function is:

```
function enviaVaga(form){
    console.log(form);
    return $http.post(constants.path+'json.php', {form}).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log("sucesso");
    });
}
```

This is a service function to send data to my backend

EDIT2: Just for future reference, removing the {} created the problem that my backend was expecting to receive a `form` object on `$formData`, to solve this I use `{form: form}`, that works well on Safari.

Comment: that isn't valid javascript.

Comment: Which part? Because no other browser complains about this code

Comment: Can you print `constants.path` value? you may need to add a slash to `/address.php` also it seems you are using promises, is that http.post?

Comment: constants.path is '../../../'.

Comment: what are you attempting to accomplish by passing `form` in that way?

Comment: I'm passing a object , which is form. My doubt is that it works perfectly on every other browser, but Safari.

Comment: You may not need {} on your form since form is already an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't passing anything valid for `data`. Safari is attempting to interpret `{form}` as a new object.

Other browsers may be more gracious, but just drop the `{` and `}`.

Actually, other browser might be interpreting `{form}` as object short notation which is not supported by safari. see: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#object_literal_extensions

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Weird that only Safari complains about that. Would strict mode help finding this out on other browsers ?

Comment: no. strict mode solves a different set of problems. you can run it thru jshint.

Comment: @BrunoHenrique thats because its on the bleeding edge.