# Token not provided

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, safari

im building a application using angular and laravel, but im having a really strange issue, in one of my links application im getting a "Token not provided", and the strangest part is that only gives me in Safari, in the other browsers it works fine, doesnt someone have a idea whats the problem?

Comment: A link? In your application? Strange issue? Please do tell more lol

Comment: Sounds like the cookie configurations of Safari aren't right. Disable CSRF protection (only for testing!!) and try it again on Safari. If it works, your browser cfg isn't correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Js angular bug only on Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689427/js-angular-bug-only-on-safari)